# Why do I need to convert my two variables from int to long long int in the provided case?

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer-overflow, cp

I was solving a programming question (problem 633 on Leetcode).

The below code does not run, it gives this error:

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 829921 + 2146654224 cannot be represented in type 'int'

```
bool judgeSquareSum(int c)
{
    int h=sqrt(c),l=0;
    
    while(l<=h)
    {
        long long sum=l*l+h*h;
        if(sum>c)
        {
            h--;
        }
        else
            if(sum<c)
                l++;
            else
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Whereas the below code runs perfectly. The only difference is, variables `l` and `h` are of `long long` type as compared to `int` type in the above code.

To specify - `l` and `h` cannot have values greater than `INT_MAX` neither `l*l` and `h*h` can be greater than `INT_MAX`.

```
bool judgeSquareSum(int c) {
    long long l = 0, h = sqrt(c);
    while (h >= l) {
        long long xxxx = l * l + h * h;
        if (xxxx > c) {
            h--;
        } else if (xxxx < c) {
            l++;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `int` is usually 32 bits, which means it has a range of about minux two billion to plus two billion. `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide, and have a *much* wider range of values.

Comment: *To specify- l and h cannot have values greater than INT_MAX* -- Doesn't that answer your question?  What if `l` and `h` are `INT_MAX - 1`?  What would this calculation give you: `l * l + h * h;`?  What gets calculated on the right side of the `=` sign has nothing to do with the variable type on the left-hand side of `=`.  You are going to be multiplying an `int` by an `int`, giving you an `int`.  By the time the `=` kicks in, you've already "corrupted" the result with the overflow.

Comment: More to the point, with the `int` variables `l` and `h`, the expression `l*l+h*h` can overflow which leads to *undefined behavior*.You need both `l` and `h` to be a larger type to not risk `int` overflow.

Comment: It's not only that `l` or `h` can be larger than `INT_MAX`, it's that `l * l` or `h * h` can't be larger than `INT_MAX`. ***And*** that the ***sum*** of both can't be larger than `INT_MAX`. As in the runtime error message: You add a small result from `l * l` with a large result from `h * h`, leading to such an overflow. The value of `c` must therefore be large (presumably `2146654224` since the result of `sqrt(c) * sqrt(c)` equals that value).

Comment: Just because the numbers themselves can't be greater than `INT_MAX` doesn't mean their sum can't be.  What's `INT_MAX + INT_MAX`?

Comment: Put in `c=2^31-1`, after `h=46340, l=296` you get `l=297` with signed overflow. Those are not the numbers of the error message with `h=46332` and l=911`

Comment: HINT: If you implement the code correctly you can use just `int`. No need for any `long long`.   The integer overflow is a red herring.

Comment: @Sebastian it turns out there are a huge number of inputs that cycle through that combination of `l` and `h`, the lowest of which I found is 2147482325.  Don't know why there's not an error before that.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you precisely what the problem is:

> signed integer overflow: 829921 + 2146654224 cannot be represented in type 'int'

You're trying to add the values 829921 and 2146654224 and the result (which should be 2147484145) does not fit in an `int`.  This tells us that you're almost certainly running on a machine where `INT_MAX` is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or 2147483647

This would appear to be coming from the line

```
long long xxxx = l * l + h * h;
```

where `l` and `h` both have type `int` so the expression `l * l + h * h` will be evaluated as type `int`.  The fact that the value will be used to initialize a value of type `long long` is irrelevant -- in C (and C++) the type and precision of expression is determined *solely* from the types of the operands and not from how the result will be used.

---

You can avoid overflow by being careful with your operations.  Since you know that `c` fits in an int and `h` and `l` are always <= sqrt(c), so `h * h` and `l * l` don't overflow, it's only the sum that overflows.  So you can rewrite your code as:

```
bool judgeSquareSum(int c) {
    int l = 0, h = sqrt(c);
    while (h >= l) {
        int xxxx = l * l - c + h * h;
        if (xxxx > 0) {
            h--;
        } else if (xxxx < 0) {
            l++;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and not need larger types

Comment: OP's naive calculation of `l * l + h * h` is not the best way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Spencer that's the second comment you've made implying a bug in the OP's algorithm, but I can't find it.  Mind enlightening us?

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, OP is working off leetcode. It's not exactly homework but the point is figuring out the solution yourself. I will say, however,  that it's  possible to check if c = h^2+l^2 without risking integer overflow by calculating `h*h+l*l`.

Comment: @Spencer yes I understand that the point of leetcode is being able to find the trick that makes it simple.  But I don't see a problem with OP's code that would produce the observed error, even if it's not optimal.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's just an unfortunate consequence of using signed integers (as opposed to unsigned) that there are chances for overflow with that algorithm. One of Sebastian's comments to OP  contains one.

Comment: @Spencer: if the argument `c` was unsigned, then using `unsigned` for h and l in this algortihm would overflow.  The problem is using a type that is the same size as c, when you need one that is at least one bit larger, given the way the code is written.

Comment: Yes, the inherent flaw of OP's code is that in order for h to decrease, you need to calculate a number greater than the original number -- but what if the original number is the maximum possible?  Anyway, you gave the solution I would have given OP. There are ways to make the algorithm faster, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

`long long` has a size of at least 64 bits. `int` has at least a size of 16 bits. Therefore not all numbers that you can represent in `long long` can also be represented as `int` without value loss, hence the need for the larger type. See more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: `int` can be longer than 32 bits.

Comment: It is even allowed that `int` is the same as `long long int` and covers the same values, but on typical PC architectures `int` is (16 bits or) 32 bits, and `long long int` is 64 bits.